# how to pass dynamic data in pluto menu? Flutter +Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, pub.dev

Im using this package https://pub.dev/packages/pluto_menu_bar . I want to know do we have any easy way to add dynamic data and select them on tap,
when I had passed static data and its working fine but when larger data  coming from the Database its not working

```
PlutoMenuItem(
              title: 'Province',
              children: [
                PlutoMenuItem.checkbox(
                  title: 'Sindh',
                  initialCheckValue: false,
                  onChanged: (flag) {
                    flag == true
                        ? provinceSelectedList.add("Sindh")
                        : provinceSelectedList.remove("Sindh");
                   
                  },
                ),]
```

Comment: Share your code example, pls

Comment: please take a quick tour [SOF Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to get  a better idea on how to properly ask well formatted questions. we will surely be needing more details and and overview of your code/progress in order to help you out! Happy coding!